# Angular js binding list of data dynamically based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iufSVUW66O2DjNMqsziA?p=preview)

Here the button opens a modal which has a table. When an item in the table is checked or unchecked, it changes the values in the progress bar accordingly.

Below the table, it has a list of all the checked courses shown. How do i bind this data accordingly such that when a checkbox is checked, it also shows the item in this list dynamically? Here is the code i used for displaying this list of items:

```
        <div ng-repeat="child in selectedCourses">
          {{child.course.subject}}-{{child.course.course_no}}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you push the same items many times into `$scope.selectedCourses`, which results into an error (because of duplicate values in `ngRepeat`ed items) which in turn causes the view to not be updated.

To prevent adding the same item many time, you should check if it is already present in the array:

```
$scop.checkplanneddetails = function (course) {
    ...
    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.planneddetails.length; k++) {
        if ($scope.requirementcoursename==$scope.planneddetails[k].course_name) {
            if (!$scope.checkcoursefunction($scope.selectedCourses, course)) {
                // ONLY add the course if it is NOT already present
                $scope.selectedCourses.push(course);
            }
            course.checked = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

There is also a problem with using `ng-checked="checkplanneddetails(child)`, because `checkplanneddetails` is not idempotent. You should not use it with `ngChecked`, because it is run every time a $digest cycle takes place.
You should `ngInit` instead and also make sure you add `course.checked = true` at the proper place inside `checkplanneddetails` (see above):

```
<!-- Change that: -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkplanneddetails(child)" ... />

<!-- To this: -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="checkplanneddetails(child)" ... />
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HtR8vjEJLfzWxqfaiKHB?p=preview)**.

Comment: its working great for the values that are checked newly. But when i uncheck on ENVR-1402, it is not splicing it. Is there another error in the code i wrote?

Comment: I forgot to mention you should check out my updated answr, but obviously you did already :)

Comment: hi i am having some trouble in one of the questions. Can you help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965379/angular-js-toggle-checkbox-function-to-disable-checkboxes